# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() for regex

Tags: python

for the following question: Find a list of all of the names in the following string using regex.
I have written this code:

```
import re
def names():
    simple_string = """Amy is 5 years old, and her sister Mary is 2 years old. 
    Ruth and Peter, their parents, have 3 kids."""
    names= re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]*", simple_string)
    print(names)
    print(len(names))
names()
```

It gives the correct output like this:
`**['Amy', 'Mary', 'Ruth', 'Peter'] , 4**`
However when I use this :
`**assert len(names()) == 4, "There are four names in the simple_string"**`
it gives me this error:
`**object of type 'NoneType' has no len()**`
I don't know where is the error in function names, can anybody help?
note: I can't change the assert function, it's inside the question.

Comment: `len(names)` not `len(names())`

Comment: @G.Anderson I don't see how that question is related

Comment: @jordanm because the function returns None implicitly, and I assume the OP is trying to return the length of the function output, not the length of the similarly named variable inside the function

Comment: @jordanm you may be misunderstanding the question—OP is asking about something *outside the function* `names`, not referring to the *variable* `names`

Answer (score 3):

`names()` does not return anything, therefore `len()` will not work. Try adding
`return(names)`. I would also avoid using function names for variable names inside the function.

Comment: There is no need for parenthesis. Just `return names` is enough.

Comment: @darcamo sorry, R syntax is sneaking in

Answer (score 1):

While you are *printing* the output of `names()` to `sys.stdout`, you are not *returning* the value of your `names` variable that's within it, meaning that the function itself returns `None`. Add `return names` to the end of your function to make that other code work.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `len(names())` this is asking for the length of what the names function returns. It returns nothing, so you're getting the NoneType error message.